# How to reliably know that HTTPServer in a separate thread is up and serving?

Tags: python, multithreading, simplehttpserver

I'm starting a `HTTPServer` object in a new thread:

```py
from http.server import HTTPServer, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
import threading

with HTTPServer(("localhost", 8080), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler) as httpd:
    thread = threading.Thread(target=httpd.serve_forever, daemon=True)
    thread.start()
    # Doing my work ...
    httpd.shutdown()
```

Here, I would like to ensure that `httpd.serve_forever()` has successfully started before `# doing my work...` is reached. I can certainly insert `thread.join(timeout=1)` after `thread.start()`, but this still risks race condition. Is there a reliable way to wait until `serve_forever` is up and running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure thing. There's a [callback called `service_actions`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/socketserver.html#socketserver.BaseServer.service_actions) which is called after every iteration of the `serve_forever` loop, and you can use a `threading.Event()` in there you can wait on.

Since the callback is called *after* each possibly serviced request, it will cause an initial delay of up to 0.5 seconds (by default), but I don't think that's a problem. If it is, you can override `serve_forever` to do it before the first request service.

```
import threading
from http.server import HTTPServer, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler


class SignalingHTTPServer(HTTPServer):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.ready_event = threading.Event()

    def service_actions(self):
        self.ready_event.set()


with SignalingHTTPServer(("localhost", 8080), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler) as httpd:
    thread = threading.Thread(target=httpd.serve_forever, daemon=True)
    thread.start()
    httpd.ready_event.wait()
    # Doing my work ...
    httpd.shutdown()
```